# AS3: Determining when a displayable object is finally displayed

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, image

I am looking to determine the final event or location where it could be determined that an Image, or a UIComponent, has been rendered to the user. I need to know when it has been displayed and thus is, presuming it's not covered up or at a silly location, visible to the user.

In the [UpdateComplete Event Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#event%3aupdateComplete) it says:

> This is the last opportunity to alter the component before it is displayed. All properties have been committed and the component has been measured and layed out.

Overriding the dispatchEvent on an Image shows that the UpdateComplete Event is the last one that it dispatches after an update of the .source property. Breakpointing and walking the code after that event shows that the LayoutManager seems to finish with it's actions before the Image is displayed.

I have watched the dispatchEvent on and updateDisplayList on the canvas container and no dice.

I assume that there is some higher (lower) object that I might be able to extend or listen to that would give me that final piece of information.

Help please.

===============================================

EDIT: ADDING CODE SAMPLE OF TEST APP

===============================================

NoisyImageTest.mxml - test application for watching the event loop. If you breakpoint at line 22 you see the last updateComplete event but the image is not yet displayed. Stepping through the code from there, it exits the thread after the LayoutManager but still has not updated the screen. I assume that there is a point where the systemManager or stage or some other item could say it drew the image. that is what I am looking for.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" xmlns:local="*">
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            private var imagePointer : NoisyImage;

            private function onImageLoadClick( event : MouseEvent ) : void
            {
                //start loading the image
                canvasTarget.removeAllChildren();
                imagePointer = new NoisyImage();
                imagePointer.addEventListener(FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE, onUpdateComplete);
                canvasTarget.addChild( imagePointer );
                imagePointer.source = 'http://helios.gsfc.nasa.gov/image_euv_press.jpg';
            }  

            private function onImageLoadClick2( event : MouseEvent ) : void
            {
                if ( imagePointer )
                {
                    imagePointer.source = 'http://helios.gsfc.nasa.gov/30dor_qdw_big.gif';
                }
            }

            private function onUpdateComplete( event : FlexEvent ) : void
            {
                trace('percentLoaded ' + ( event.target as NoisyImage ).percentLoaded );
                trace('bytesLoaded ' + ( event.target as NoisyImage ).bytesLoaded );
                trace('content ' + ( event.target as NoisyImage ).content );
                if ( event.target.source )
                {
                    trace('onUpdateComplete has valid source.');
                    if ( event.target.width )
                    {
                        trace('onUpdateComplete has valid width.');                    
                    }
                }

            }             
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <local:NoisyCanvas id="canvasTarget" width="500" height="400" horizontalCenter="0" />
    <mx:Button label="load image" click="onImageLoadClick(event)" horizontalCenter="0" />
    <mx:Button label="sticth source to image2" click="onImageLoadClick2(event)" horizontalCenter="0" />
</s:Application>
```

NoisyCanvas.as - this is the canvas the noisyImage will be placed in that provides all the traces on dispatched events

```
package
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    import mx.containers.Canvas;

    public class NoisyCanvas extends Canvas
    {
        public function NoisyCanvas()
        {
            super();
        }

        override public function dispatchEvent(event:Event):Boolean
        {
            trace( 'c dispatchEvent: ' + event );
            return super.dispatchEvent(event);
        }

        override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
        {
            trace( 'c updateDisplayList: ' + unscaledWidth + ' ' + unscaledHeight );
            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
        }

        override protected function childrenCreated():void
        {
            trace( 'c childrenCreated' );
            super.childrenCreated();
        }        
    }
}
```

NoisyImage.as - this is the image that provides all the traces on dispatched events

```
package
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    import mx.controls.Image;

    public class NoisyImage extends Image
    {
        public function NoisyImage()
        {
            super();
        }

        override public function dispatchEvent(event:Event):Boolean
        {
            trace( 'i dispatchEvent: ' + event );
            return super.dispatchEvent(event);
        }

        override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
        {
            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
            trace( 'i updateDisplayList: ' + unscaledWidth + ' ' + unscaledHeight );
        }        
    }        
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Just get the last location of when a component has been rendered? updateComplete is the event for you. It's almost impossible to know if it has a direct line of sight to the user without some kind of crazy engine (that would probably be inefficient).

Comment: is the display object a custom component?

Comment: @J_A_X I am trying to determine when an image is rendered so that I can capture it. The app is compositing it with other images and text for a final presentation that is captured. I need to do multiple frames speedily and thus know definitively that the image has been displayed if essential.

Comment: @The_asman The display object may be a custom component. If there were a way to determine this I'd be happy to create one.

Comment: Capture it?  Stop being abstract and get to what you're trying to accomplish.  Imagery could be helpful.

Comment: @J_A_X I have a tool that allows a user to upload images and video and add text overlays and a slew of other animation options. They have a timeline and can upload image sequences as well. Once they have completed their project I am grabbing the contents of this canvas as a series of bitmap frames and piping it over to ffmpeg to generate a movie. To be able to do this I need ot determine when an image that I have asked to load is on the canvas so that I can do the bitmapData.draw( this ) call on the canvas to get the frame

Comment: So, at the base level, I am looking for a method by which I can determine that an image that I have asked to load is displayed so that the draw call will capture it. I want to do this quickly and accurately and thus am looking for a definitive event or place that I could extend to issue an event that says this image is displayed and ready.

Comment: why not just listen to the image loader for the complete event

Comment: @The_asMan [Event.complete](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/SWFLoader.html#event:complete) is issued when the content is loaded and tells the image that it is ready to be displayed but not that it has been displayed. I traced out all the events that the Image issues and the sequence looks like: open, (a bunch of) progress, init, httpStatus, **complete**, updateDisplayList (not an event), updateComplete. And breakpointing at the updateComplete the image still was not displayed so it's past that point in the thread.

Comment: Interesting, updateDisplaylist is called because something invalidated the list so it should be showing at that point. Maybe try to override the draw( ) method and see where that falls into place

Comment: Seems like it would be easier, once the user completes their project, to do all the rendering behind the scenes instead of waiting on screen updates.

Comment: @takteek That sounds great except that I'm not sure how to do the rendering with the filter effects and the layered images and text without using the the screen updates. The bitmapData.draw() routine only grabs the pixels that have been sent to the screen. Is there something I have overlooked that would allow me to grab the combined pixel data before the screen update?

Comment: BitmapData.draw() doesn't have to iterate on the screen, actually. What you could do is try a blitting technique - take all of your layers, text, whatever, and use BitmapData.copyPixels to copy them all to an empty BitmapData that is the size of the stage. (Note: It doesn't have to be on the displaylist for this to work.) Google "Blitting in AS3" to get a better idea of what I'm talking about. If need be, I can show you some code that I wrote for a game engine that uses copyPixels to draw layer data to a single BitmapData canvas.

Comment: @lunchmeat317 thanks for the tip. I'll look into Blitting. I have no qualms with doing the composite in the background if I can reproduce what they would see on the display. That example you mentioned would be spectacular. Thanks.

Comment: I'll try to post some code for you tonight, if possible. I think I've got a solution - I'll just have to code it out.

Comment: @Sam I don't know if I rock, per se. I might just boogie a little bit. Let me know if you have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

okay....I thought I had a solution. Unfortunately, I really don't know flex, but I can provide the Blitting classes that I created.

I'm hoping that you can use these (or, at least, the ideas encapsulated) to find a solution that will help you. I do believe it's possible - I just don't know the Flex objects well enough to implement it.

Also, note that these classes were created for a game I'm trying to make, so feel free to excise anything you don't need. There are some uncompleted methods, as well. It's a bit sloppy. :-\

```
// Oh, and, please ignore my code comments, I tend to talk to myself.
```

Class BLOB is the base object for many of these classes, composed of a [bitmapData](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html) object. The rect and point variables were for my [copyPixels](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#copyPixels%28%29) operations; you may be able to pull those values from your objects themselves.

```
package com.lunchmeat317.blitter
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    /**
     * ...
     * @author lunchmeat317
     */
    public class BLOB
    // BLOB stands for BLit OBject.
    {
        // These are the core variables of this class. Debating whether to make these
        // internal or protected. Protected is logical, but are getters slower for
        // parsing?

        internal var data:BitmapData;
        internal var rect:Rectangle;
        internal var point:Point;

        // To be used with scrollrect in order to animate frames. Frameoffset...shit.
        // Do I pull these values from rect.width and rect.height? Is this necessary?
        // Maybe I should just make these booleans? Perhaps these value can be the
        // quotient of the rect dims from the bitmap dims? No idea. (That could help
        // with wrapping.)
        private var frameoffset:uint;

        // Variable that determines whether to blit this object or not. Blitting engine
        // will check this condition for each object it blits. True by default.
        private var visible:Boolean;

        public function BLOB(width:uint, height:uint, x_pos:int, y_pos:int, x_rectpos:uint, y_rectpos:uint, image:BitmapData)
        {
            data = image;
            rect = new Rectangle(x_rectpos, y_rectpos, width, height);
            point = new Point(x_pos, y_pos);

            visible = true;

            data.lock();
        }

        public function setVisibleState(value:Boolean):void
        {
            visible = value;
        }

        public function getVisibleState():Boolean
        {
            return visible;
        }

        public function setLocation(location:Point):void
        {
            point = location;
        }

        public function getLocation():Point
        {
            return point;
        }

        public function move(dx:Number, dy:Number):void
        {
            point.offset(dx, dy);
        }
    }
}
```

Class BlitLayerCanvas is basically a [bitmapData](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html) that you can [copyPixels()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#copyPixels%28%29) individual bitmaps to, but it doesn't appear onscreen because it's not added to the displaylist. Hopefully, looking at this class will help you to copy objects to a canvas that exists in memory, but not on display. (Tip: If you know you aren't going to add it to the displaylist, you don't actually need to use the [Bitmap](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Bitmap.html) container class.)

```
package com.lunchmeat317.blitter
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author lunchmeat317
     */
    public final class BlitLayerCanvas extends BLOB
    {
        public var bloblist:Vector.<BLOB>;

        public function BlitLayerCanvas(width:uint, height:uint, x_pos:int, y_pos:int, x_rectpos:uint, y_rectpos:uint)
        {
            super(width, height, x_pos, y_pos, x_rectpos, y_rectpos, new BitmapData(width, height, true, 0x0));

            bloblist = new Vector.<BLOB>();
        }

        public function addObject(obj:BLOB):void
        {
            bloblist.push(obj);
            trace("BLOB added to bloblist");
        }

        public function update():void
        {
            for each (var x:BLOB in bloblist)
            {
                data.copyPixels(x.data, x.rect, x.point, null, null, true);
            }
        }

        public function flush():void
        {
            data.fillRect(data.rect, 0x0);
        }
    }
}
```

There are two more classes, but they're pretty much the same concept - one class for layers without a canvas (basically, a vector of BLOBs) and the final class that updates the screen. They work the same way.

I know this is kind of a handful, and I wish that I could be more informative. This definitely isn't the best answer in the world, but I hope that my code snippets can at least get you pointed in the right direction. Let me know if you have any questions and I'll try to answer them.

Good luck.